# PHP curl: Can't get site content - cookies issue?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to get content of this site: `http://www.gratka.pl/`, but I recieve only this:

> * About to connect() to gratka.pl port 80
>   *   Trying 195.8.99.42... * connected
>   * Connected to gratka.pl (195.8.99.42) port 80
>   GET / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2
>   Host: gratka.pl
>   Accept: */*
>
> < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   < Cache-Control: no-cache
>   < Content-length: 0
>   < Location: ..
>   * Connection #0 to host gratka.pl left intact
>   * Issue another request to this URL: 'http://blad.gratka.pl/403.html'
>   * About to connect() to blad.gratka.pl port 80
>   * Trying 195.8.99.1... * connected
>   * Connected to blad.gratka.pl (195.8.99.1) port 80
>   GET /403.html HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2
>   Host: blad.gratka.pl
>   Accept: */*
>   ...
>   < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   < Cache-Control: no-cache
>   < Content-length: 0
>   < Location: http://blad.gratka.pl/403.html
>   * Connection #1 to host blad.gratka.pl left intact
>   * Maximum (20) redirects followed
>   * Closing connection #0
>   * Closing connection #1

What means that script which I always use to grab content isn't working:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 15;
    $cookie_file_path = 'c.txt';
    $fp = fopen($cookie_file_path, "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $url = 'http://gratka.pl';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    $info = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

After executing script cookie file (c.txt) is empty. What's wrong? Maybe site needs valid cookies or maybe it's matter of correct HTTP headers? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: When I execute above script on my localhost it's working, but it's not working when executing on dedicated server. Any guess?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, I tried my code on another server and it worked. I guess my first server was banned. :)

I guess gratka points to http://blad.gratka.pl/403.html, when they do not want you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is Correct. Just add this line to `curl section`

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $data;
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, but still same problem - this time it looks like this: * About to connect() to gratka.pl port 80
*   Trying 195.8.99.42... * connected
* Connected to gratka.pl (195.8.99.42) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: gratka.pl
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15